# How to make a constraint based in a entry value in an Association Object in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following minimal example:

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = "association_table"
    left_id = Column(ForeignKey("left_table.id"), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(ForeignKey("right_table.id"), primary_key=True)
    first_child = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "left_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "right_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```

How to make a constraint that only one child could be the first child of a parent? (Disregarding the 'couple first child' logic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to use the *Partial Index*, which are supported for [PostgreSQL, Partial Indexes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#partial-indexes) and [SQLite, Partial Indexes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#partial-indexes).

The code below should work for both:

```py
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = "association_table"
    left_id = Column(ForeignKey("left_table.id"), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(ForeignKey("right_table.id"), primary_key=True)
    first_child = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            "uci_first_child",
            left_id,
            unique=True,
            postgres_where=first_child==True,  # will be used for postgresql
            sqlite_where=first_child==True,    # will be used for sqlite
        ),
    )
```